# Showing that $f$ has a logaritimic modulus of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, metric-spaces

A modulus of continuity is a continuous, increasing, concave function $\omega:[0, \infty)\to [0, \infty)$
such that $\omega(0)=0$.  We say that a function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is $\omega$-Hölder continuous function
if for some positive constant $C$, we have
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C\omega(d(x,y)) \quad \text{for all } x,y\in X.
$$
If $f$ is a $\omega$-Hölder continuous function,  we define
$$
 \text{Hol}_\omega(f)=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{\omega(d(x,y))}.
$$
We refer to $C_{b}(X,\mathbb{R})$ as the Banach space of all
real-valued bounded continuous functions endowed with its  supremum
norm $\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$.
We use the notation $C^{\omega}(X)$
to denote the space of all bounded real-valued $\omega$-H"older functions on $X$, endowed with the norm
$$
\|f\|_\omega=\|f\|_\infty+\text{Hol}_\omega(f).
$$
It is easy to see that the normed  space $(C^\omega(X),\|\cdot\|_{\omega})$ is a Banach algebra, that is,
it is a Banach space and the following inequality holds $\|fg\|_\omega\leq \|f\|_\omega\|g\|_\omega$,
for all $f,g \in C^\omega(X)$.

**My problem:** Let $X=[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ equipped with the product metric $d$ given by:
$$
d(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{|x_i-y_i|}{2^i}
$$

Define $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ by putting $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots )=x_1$. I would like to show that $f \in C^{\omega}(X)$ where
$
\omega(t)=\dfrac{t^\alpha}{|\log(t)|^\beta}
$

I was able to proof something like that when considering  $X=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ however when I switch $\{0,1\}$ to  the compact interval $[0,1]$ the my calculus do not work.

Comment: The claim holds iff $\alpha<1 $ and $\beta>0$ or $\alpha=1$ and $\beta =0.$

Comment: Could you give some reference or provide me some direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as Ryszard Szwarc mentions in the comments. In fact, it is true exactly when there is some $C>0$ with $t \leq C\omega(t)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, which is the case when $\alpha \in [0,1)$ and $\beta \geq 0$ or $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta=0$ (assuming both are non-negative). Indeed, one can easily verify that $f$ is bounded by 1, whereas if $t\leq C\omega(t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$, then for $x,y \in X$ $$|f(x)-f(y)| = |x_1-y_1| \leq 2d(x,y) \leq 2C\omega(d(x,y)).$$ This shows that $f \in C^{\omega}(X)$ with $\textrm{Hol}_{\omega}(f) \leq 2C$.

One should be a bit careful though, as your $\omega$ only satisfies the stated conditions of a modulus of continuity locally around the origin, and is not well-defined at $t=1$. This can be resolved by redefining $\omega$ away from the origin, which does not affect the argument.

Edit: to show that $t\leq C\omega(t)$, observe that it holds for $t$ away from zero since $t$ is bounded and $\omega(t)$ is lower bounded by a positive constant. Therefore, it suffices to verify that the limit $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t}{\omega(t)} = \lim_{t \to 0} t^{1-\alpha}|\log(t)|^\beta$$
is finite, which holds exactly under the conditions mentioned above.

Comment: Could you provide me some reference or provide me some direction in order the first inequality in your answer?

Comment: I have added some extra details to the answer, I hope it helps!